# Calabash android swipe not working

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

I am running an android calabash test. I have two tabs on my screen and to switch between these two tabs when I have tried **perform_action('swipe', 'right')** a small portion of the screen swiping and it goes back to the previous state without switching to the new tab. I have even tried **perform_action('drag', 86, 306, 143, 143, 10)** but getting no response. 
When I print the query getting the below-given response. Here I wanted to switch between **chats** and **contacts**.

```
{  
  "id"      =>nil,
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "text"      =>"Chats",
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@42569e98",
  "class"      =>"android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>157,
     "center_x"         =>119,
     "height"         =>29,
     "y"         =>143,
     "width"         =>67,
     "x"         =>86
  }
},
{  
  "id"      =>nil,
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView@4256b740",
  "class"      =>"android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>158,
     "center_x"         =>360,
     "height"         =>72,
     "y"         =>122,
     "width"         =>240,
     "x"         =>240
  }
},
{  
  "id"      =>nil,
  "enabled"      =>true,
  "contentDescription"      =>nil,
  "text"      =>"Contacts",
  "visible"      =>true,
  "tag"      =>nil,
  "description"      =>"android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@4256c690",
  "class"      =>"android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView",
  "rect"      =>      {  
     "center_y"         =>157,
     "center_x"         =>359,
     "height"         =>29,
     "y"         =>143,
     "width"         =>107,
     "x"         =>306
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is enough.no need to use the **perform_action** method.
`Then /^I pan right $/ do
 pan_right()
 end`

Answer (score 2):

Those are very old and deprecated actions. I suggest just using `pan_left` or similar. You can specify the percentage coords for those methods

Comment: The above one has been working so far. But right now it seems like not. Whenever I run the test without display swipe right is not happening.